# How to import neo4j dump into the current database

Tags: neo4j

I can get a dump of the current database as following:

```
neo4j-shell -c dump > dump.sql
```

Now how do I import that dump file into another database (using the shell)

Comment: Please note that the `.sql` extension is confusing. The dump command dumps to cypher query language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
neo4j-shell -file dump.sql
```

The shell will exit after executing the file. See http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.2/re02.html